# How did Vastra, Jenny, and Strax all live a century while the Doctor was brooding?

Tags: doctor-who

Between the events of The Angels Take Manhattan and The Snowmen, it is stated explicitly that the Doctor became a brooding recluse in Victorian London for a hundred years. In Snowmen, Vastra says that "we assist him in his isolation", presumably implying that they were with him that entire time. I'm not sure about lifespans of Silurians or Sontarans, but Jenny was a normal human, and she didn't remotely age. How is this possible?

Comment: Apparently Sontarans' lifespans are even shorter. In "A Good Man Goes to War" when Strax gets injured he says "It's all right, I've had a long life. I'm almost twelve".

Comment: @tilley31 Well, that's all the Sontarans who are in wars that are dying there. We don't know how long one might live if it's not constantly subjected to brutal battles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misremembering some line, the words "hundred" and "century" don't appear anywhere in the dialogue in [this transcript of The Snowmen](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/33-6.htm). The Doctor does say "Over a thousand years of saving the universe", but he's referring to his entire life since his first incarnation "borrowed" the TARDIS, not his life since the events of The Angels Take Manhattan.

Comment: I was wondering about that too...